# How to update the combo's content when its store was modified locally. EXTJS 4.2

Tags: extjs4.2

My problem is the following: I have a store already loaded by calling an URL, it is used by a combo to display a list of values. Locally I update the store meaning that I use its "add" method to add a new record to the store.

I would like to find a way to refresh the combo's list to reflect also the new added value, but without any other "store.load()" call, since the store contains the new value.
I want to achieve this just by manipulating the store, not the combo (because I have 7 combos depending on that store).

Any ideas, please? 
I should mention that I use "comboName.bindStore(storeInstance)" method the create the link between the combo and the store.
I also should mention that I tried to fire the 'refresh' event on the store after I added the new record, but the combo still doesn't display the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually it was my fault. I was adding an incorrect record into the store. Once I solved that problem, the combo updates its records just fine when the store changes its content.